# Program hangs on printf or skips printf

Tags: c

My program is to get the file size every so often and display it to record any changes. For some reason executing the code below hangs and just provides me with a cursor. Nothing is printed or displayed.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc != 3)
  {
    printf("ERROR: Please enter correct amount of arguments."); 
    exit(0);
  }

  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  int time = atoi(argv[2]);
  int size=0;

  printf("Seconds File Size");

  while(1)
  {
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fp);

    sleep(4);
  }
  fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: You don't check the result of `fopen()`. *You don't flush the output buffer* before going into an infinite loop. You never quit or do any output in the loop.

Comment: Ummm... what @John3136 said. Why not make that an answer? Too easy?

Comment: `printf()` doesn't automatically append a newline (which typically triggers a flush), so either flush the buffer or add a `\n` depending on your intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you output a string to a buffer and then enter an infinite loop before ensuring the buffer is flushed to the screen.

```
printf("Seconds File Size");
fflush(stdout);
```

Other problems:

1. You don't check the result of `fopen()`
2. There is no way to exit your infinite loop.